# Push notifications parameters

Tags: android, iphone, ios, push-notification, push

I would like to ask you about parameters of push notifications to iOS and Android devices. My questions is:

What is possible to send to both types of devices? I mean some limitations of string I send, subject, action buttons etc. We need to support "old" devices like iPhone 3g. Is there some differences between banner or alert (user settup) in iOS 5. What about Android?

We would like to send user some text with possibility to open our app.

Many thanks for your answers.

Kind regards,
Tomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS there is a limitation of 256 Bytes Payload for the Push Notification what isn't quite much. You cannot modify the AlertView that will be shown to the user when the notifaction arrives. It just has these two buttons (view and close. View will open the app). But the Notification is the same for all the iOS versions.